# how can i get user last login info and send email to last login reminder?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want make system send email alert to inactive user, who is not logged it for last 7 days or 1 month. how can i do that?

```
    // user last login reminder
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
 update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'inactivity_reminder' ) ) {
 wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'inactivity_reminder' );
}
function inactivity_reminder() {
 $users = new WP_User_Query( [
   'role'         => ['student', 'author'],
   'meta_key'     => 'last_login',
   'meta_value'   => strtotime( '7days' ),
   'meta_compare' => '<',
 ] );
 foreach( $users->get_results() as $user ) {
   $to = $user->user_email;
   $subject = "Inactivity Notice";
   $message = "ALERT.......... We notice you have not logged in for 20 days.";
   wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message);
 }
}
add_action( 'inactivity_reminder', 'inactivity_reminder' );

// user last login reminder
function user_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
 update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'user_last_login', 10, 2 );
if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'inactivity_reminder' ) ) {
 wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'inactivity_reminder' );
}
function inactivity_reminder() {
 $users = new WP_User_Query( [
   'role'         => ['student', 'author'],
   'meta_key'     => 'last_login',
   'meta_value'   => strtotime( '7days' ),
   'meta_compare' => '<',
 ] );
 foreach( $users->get_results() as $user ) {
   $to = $user->user_email;
   $subject = "Inactivity Notice";
   $message = "ALERT.......... We notice you have not logged in for 20 days.";
   wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message);
 }
}
add_action( 'inactivity_reminder', 'inactivity_reminder' );
```

I tried with above code but did not worked. I checked the user mail, there is no alert massage after 1 week.

Comment: Is there any relationship with WordPress for this question ?

Comment: Have you checked PHP error logs and mail error logs? If so, please publish the available stack traces here.

Comment: Yes i tried this code in a WordPress website, in functions.php.
I found no errors also there was no output or result of this script.